# YouCompleteMe не работает с заголовочными файлами

Tags: c++, vim

Недавно решил установить `YouCompleteMe` и обнаружил, что, несмотря на то, что все прекрастно работает с `.cpp` файлами, тем не менее автодополнение не работает корректно с `.hpp` файлами. Так, например, если в `.cpp` файлах я ставлю `::` то мне сразу выдается список всех функций и классов в глобальном пространстве имен. Но не в `.hpp` файлах. Как это настроить?

Comment: Не совсем уверен, но думаю никак.

Comment: каким именно образом YCM в твоём случае получает флаги для компиляции? скорей всего можно будет решить создав глобальный `.ycm_extra_conf.py`

Comment: @Fat-Zer он получает флаги от cmake через файл compile_comands.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать специальный скрипт `.ycm_extra_conf.py`, который будет выдавать флаги для компиляции для тех файлов, которых нет в базе данных. Конкретных реализаций может быть несколько, но один из вариантов конфигурации, который я использую у себя приведён ниже.

#### ~/.vim/ycm_extra_conf.py

ЕМНИП основан на одном из .ycm_extra_conf.py в самом ycm'е

```
#
# This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
#

import os
import ycm_core
import re

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set (by default, one is not set).
# CHANGE THIS LIST OF FLAGS. YES, THIS IS THE DROID YOU HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR.
def_flags = [
  '-fexceptions'
]

forse_flags = [
  '-Wall',
  '-Wextra'
]

def Log(msg):
  pass
#  with open("/tmp/ycm_extra_conf.log", "a") as f: 
#    f.write("%s\n" % msg)

Log("loading extraconfig file")
if ( os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/compile_commands.json") ):
  compilation_database_folder = os.getcwd()
else:
  compilation_database_folder = ''

if os.path.exists( compilation_database_folder ):
  Log ("Found compilation database")
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  Log ("Compilation database not found")
  database = None

C_SOURCE_EXTENTION = [ '.c' ]
CPP_SOURCE_EXTENTION = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc' ]
OBJECTIVE_C_SOURCE_EXTENTION = [ '.m', '.mm' ]
SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = C_SOURCE_EXTENTION + CPP_SOURCE_EXTENTION + OBJECTIVE_C_SOURCE_EXTENTION

def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )

def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return list( flags )
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

      if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags

def GetExtension( filename ):
    return os.path.splitext( filename )[ 1 ];

def IsHeaderFile( filename ):
  return GetExtension(filename) in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh' ]


def GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename ):
  # The compilation_commands.json file generated by CMake does not have entries
  # for header files. So we do our best by asking the db for flags for a
  # corresponding source file, if any. If one exists, the flags for that file
  # should be good enough.
  if IsHeaderFile( filename ):
    basename = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 0 ]
    for extension in SOURCE_EXTENSIONS:
      replacement_file = basename + extension
      if os.path.exists( replacement_file ):
        compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile(
          replacement_file )
        if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:
          return compilation_info
    return None
  return database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )

def LangForFile( filename ):
    # determine lang (-x) flag
    lang = None
    extension = GetExtension (filename)

    # set the language according to file extension
    if extension in C_SOURCE_EXTENTION:
        Log("Language determined as C because of extension")
        lang = "c"
    elif extension in CPP_SOURCE_EXTENTION:
        Log("Language determined as C++ because of extension")
        lang = "c++"
    elif IsHeaderFile(filename):
        Log("Determin language for header")
        # .h header might fit both c and c++, if there is a cpp file in the same dir, use C++
        # otherwise use C
        for ext in CPP_SOURCE_EXTENTION:
            if os.path.exists( basename + ext ):
                lang = 'c++'
                break
        if not lang:
            for ext in C_SOURCE_EXTENTION:
                if os.path.exists( basename + ext ):
                    lang = 'c'
                    break
        if not lang:
            # neither c nor cpp file of the same name, lets count which  of them more in the dir
            c_num = 0
            cpp_num = 0
            for f in os.listdir( os.path.dirname(filename) ):
                if os.path.splitext( f )[ 1 ] in C_SOURCE_EXTENTION   : c_num   += 1 
                if os.path.splitext( f )[ 1 ] in CPP_SOURCE_EXTENTION : cpp_num += 1 
            if c_num>cpp_num:
                lang="c"
            else: # even if there is equal count of both, give up it and use c++
                lang = "c++"
    # no fall back... let clang to decide
    return lang


def CustomFlagsForFile( filename ):
    rv = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            m = re.match (r'\s*//\s*c(xx)?flags:(.*)', line)
            if m:
                rv += m.group(2).split()
            m = re.match (r'\s*//\s*pkg-config cflags:(.*)', line)
            if m:
                for word in m.group(1).split():
                    cmd = "pkg-config --cflags " + word;
                    Log ("Running '" + cmd + "'")
                    rv += os.popen (cmd).read().split()
    return rv


def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    if not compilation_info:
      Log("no compilation info found")
      return None

    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
      compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
      compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ )
  else:
    Log("Going to use default flags")
    relative_to = os.path.dirname(filename)

    flags = def_flags
    flags += CustomFlagsForFile (filename)

    # set the language if it is determined
    lang = LangForFile( filename )
    if lang:
        Log("Appending language to flags")
        flags += ['-x', lang]
        if lang == "c++":
            flags += ["-std=c++14"]


    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  Log("Compilation flags for file \"" + str(filename) + "\" are:" + str(final_flags))

  return {
    'flags': forse_flags + final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

#### ~/.vimrc

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf="~/.vim/ycm_extra_conf.py"
```

Флаги для компиляции хедеров берутся из флагов *.c/*.cpp файлов с тем же именем. Помимо этого, скрипт дополнительно добавляет `-Wall` и `-Wextra`, а если база данных компиляции отсутствует, то угадывает язык и из пытаетсф достать флаги компиляции из файла по шаблонам `// cflags:` и `// pkg-config cflags`. Последнее предназначено по большей части для однофайловых тестовых программок.

Само собой, скрипт может потребовать подгонки под свои привычки.

Comment: Не подскажете заодно: у меня YouCompleteMe не запускает автодополнение после того, как поставил точку - с :: и -> отлично работает, но вот после точки нужно набрать еще символ, чтобы запустить автодополнение.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, извини, здесь ни каких идей... УМВР и в доках ничего подобного на вскидку не видно...

Comment: В том то и дело, кто в доках (насколько мне позволяет судить мой уровень английского) указано, что автодополнение должно автоматически включаться после `->`, `::` и `.`, но оно не включается именно после `.`, хотя работает с двумя предыдущими

Comment: из-за этого, если нужно посмотреть методы в классе, приходится нажимать `<C-Space>` после точки. Есть способ вызывать `<C-Space>` автоматом после нажатия точки?

Comment: ну да, я и имею в виду, что нет отдельных опций, которые устанавливали бы изменяли поведение дополнения именно после точки...ЗЫ: по <C-Space> же сразу дополнение выводит?

Comment: да, сразу же после нажатия комбинации

Comment: на ум приходит вот такой грязный хак: `imap . .<C-R>=<SNR>83_InvokeSemanticCompletion()<CR>`